# Docker: Why does wait-for always time out?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[This page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) discusses how to control startup order using docker-compose. It recommends three tools: *wait-for-it*, *dockerize* or *wait-for*.

I have struggled to get either *wait-for-it* or *wait-for* working as expected, but in this question I'll focus on *[wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for)*.

Each time my docker container starts, it quits with "Operation Timed Out".

Here's my very simple docker file as an example:

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY ./wait-for.sh /
WORKDIR /
RUN chmod +x ./wait-for.sh
CMD sh -c './wait-for.sh www.eficode.com:80 -- echo "Eficode site is up"'
```

This should copy the script from the current directory to the root, make it executable and set the run command to execute the script and check the status of the eficode website (example taken from the eficode github page).

[image: Image showing the error message]

I've tried supplying the timeout flag, which does adjust the timeout, but doesn't affect the result. I've also tried running this script as part of a docker-compose command (following the example on the docker-compose documentation page linked above) but, again, with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing the `netcat` package and `nc` isn't available in your example image. Add the following somewhere in your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat
```

Comment: This was it - thank you. I couldn't see the requirement documented anywhere; how did you know that netcat was the missing package? What should I look for so I can avoid this kind of issue in the future?

Comment: @andyf Wait-for is a shell script, so you can simply check the contents of the script to see the nc command. Or at least that's what I did.

Comment: I just `set -xe` at the top of the script to see where it errors. Actually, they redirect the output of the `nc` command to null which doesn't seem necessary. Changing that alone would have shown the error that the `nc` binary was not found.

Answer (score 7):

As Andy mentions, you need `nc` to be installed. You can:

- Manually install the package with his command
- Switch to wait-for-it that uses bash since your base image is ubuntu. This script doesn't need `nc` since bash can hit ports directly.
- Switch to alpine linux if you don't need bash, it ships with `nc`. That just means changing the first line to `FROM alpine`.